# Is there any way to freeze document.body.innerHTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to freeze **document.body.innerHTML** in JavaScript so that attacker will unable to do the following:

`<script>document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("http://www.example.com/" , "http://abc.org" ); </script>`

Also how to freeze document.location? Thanks!

Comment: No. Code that has the ability to run on your page can do anything to it.

Comment: @timaschew well yes that'd work, but you can't control that from the page itself. In other words, a page can't force the browser to disable JavaScript for itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't lock the contents of a DOM element from javascript. I suspect you're asking the wrong question here. What you probably need to do is plug whatever vulnerability the attacker is using to run the code in the first place.

- Sanitize user inputs to strip out tags
- Sanitize content that is inserted into the page from the DB
- Disallow html tags in any input to your application

These would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to "freeze" it. You can prevent this by not including 3rd party scripts on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Well not with JavaScript. It's simply not possible. How should your code to be more exclusiv than any else?

The simple solution is to write a secure page which is not voluble for XSS. Parse everything which comes from outside and your page will be secure.

You could also try to prevent that your site is loaded in frames with the `X-Frame-Options` header. You can achive that with a .htaccess file with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Secure frame optione
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```